# Next Auth: Email validation connection timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm following the official tutorial to set up email authentication via Next Auth (now Auth.js).

My `[...nextauth.js]` file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Email from "next-auth/providers/email";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    Email({
      server: {
        host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.SMTP_PORT),
        auth: {
          user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
          pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
  ],
  debug: true,
});
```

My `.env` file:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin:admin@localhost:3306/<db_name>"

SMTP_USER=apikey
SMTP_PASSWORD="<My sendgrind API key>"
SMTP_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
SMTP_PORT=587
EMAIL_FROM="<An email address>"
```

When I navigate to /api/auth/signin, I see the usual form:

[image]

However, when I insert an email and click the button, nothing happens. The page appears to be loading but after a number of seconds (40+) the connection just stops. Terminal has the following error message (redacted for privacy/security):

```
[next-auth][debug][adapter_getUserByEmail] { args: [ '<REDACTED>' ] }
[next-auth][debug][adapter_createVerificationToken] {
  args: [
    {
      identifier: '<REDACTED>',
      token: 'e9f23bcd33dc48c337bcd76b839919827d721181862aae6739e1ef5524e62720',
      expires: 2023-09-08T05:58:25.407Z
    }
  ]
}
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_EMAIL_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_email_error Connection timeout {
  error: {
    message: 'Connection timeout',
    stack: 'Error: Connection timeout\n' +
      '    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/workspace/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)\n' +
      '    at SMTPConnection._onError (/workspace/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:776:20)\n' +
      '    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/workspace/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)\n' +
      '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)\n' +
      '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)',
    name: 'Error'
  },
  providerId: 'email',
  message: 'Connection timeout'
```